# Low fps playback in viewport

Tags: animation, 3d-view, keyframes

[image]

Hello guys, I'm having trouble animating in real time, 24fps. I have had this problem before and could never find the answer to why the playback is always so slow.
My specs are:
amd ryzen 5 3600X
Nividia RTX2060 6gb
32gb RAM

Can someone help?

Comment: How many vertices are there in the scene?

Comment: 578k+ vertices, is that too much?